# Embedded OrientDB server for java unit testing

Tags: java, mongodb, unit-testing, junit, orientdb

Are there some projects that embeds an OrientDB server like [this embedded mongo](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo)?

I'm trying to make an agile unit test implementation and avoid setup and configuration as much as I can

Thanks

Comment: Could you please describe the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I need a zero configuration and implementation of orientdb instance to perform integration test

Answer (score 2):

You can do two thing.

If you don't need to test against a standalone server, simply set to your "database access layer" a plocal OrientDB url , e.g.: plocal:./target/testNameDb .
This gives you a very fast access, because network isn't involved. You're tests will be not so "unit", because they involved a db, even if embedded.

If you need to run "integration tests" against a live OrientDB server, you can easily run it, as suggested before, directly from java: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Embedded-Server.html

Comment: as I described the embedded mongo project allow you to perform integration test with zero configuration, just include the maven dependency and all the tests that need a connection to mongo will be satisfied. I'm looking for something like that. I already knows the embed orient db doc.

Comment: ok, I found on orientdb side projects there's a [spring-boot implementation](https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb) that delivers a zero code configuration using an in-memory db istance. I spot you as a contributor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running OrientDB with [Docker](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Docker-Home.html). So you don't need to install or configure anything. Or alternatively you can [embedd an OrientDB Server inside a Java application](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Embedded-Server.html).

Hope it helps.